# Modal backdrop is not going away after calling .hide()

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide a modal, but the modal is going away and the backdrop is staying put and not allowing me to click anything. I have to refresh the entire page for it to work

Here is my code:

```
   $("#AddNewOrganizationModal").modal('hide');
```

It seems to work in all my other modals, but I cannot pin point why this one is not being closed:

Here is the class that is showing up still:

```
   .modal-backdrop {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1040;
     background-color: #1a1a1a;
   }
```

Is there a way to remove this class just in general?

This ONLY happens when I'm on the development web site. Locally it works fine and closes without any issues.

Could something be caching on azure dev ops?

Answer (score 0):

The way that Bootstrap modals are structured, the backdrop is part of the modal container.

Here's some pseudo-code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
<modal-wrapper>
  <modal-backdrop>
    <modal-container>
      content of modal
    </modal-container>
  </modal-backdrop>
</modal-wrapper>
```

The element to which you want to apply the **hide** function is `<modal-wrapper>`. When you hide that, the `<modal-backdrop>` will also be hidden.

You are probably hiding `<modal-container>` instead, and so `<modal-backdrop>` is still displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue and had to manually force the backdrop to hide during the modal hidden event. Code similar to this:

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the answer:

```
           $('.modal-backdrop').fadeOut(150);
```